# What could be wrong with my code in uploading a photo in windows phone 8?I

Tags: c#, php, windows-phone-8, restsharp

I have copy and pasted this code from somewhere and while trying to run it, i get an exception error. What could be wrong with it?
Here is my register.php file

```
<?php
require_once("script_pages__/db_handler.php");
$db=new db_handler();
$fname=$_REQUEST['fname'];
$lname=$_REQUEST['lname'];
$username=$_REQUEST['username'];
$password=$_REQUEST['password'];
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
$dob=$_REQUEST['dob'];


if(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    if(isset($_FILES['profile'])){
    $random_file_no=rand(0000,9999);
    $media=$_FILES['profile'];
    $tmpname=$_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'];
    $name=$_FILES['profile']['name'];
    $target="Uploads/";
    $profile_pic=$random_file_no.substr($username,0,3).$name;
    $target=$target.basename($profile_pic);
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["profile"]["tmp_name"], $target);
    $register=$db->register($fname,$lname,$username,$email,$dob,$password,$profile_pic);
    }else{
    $register=$db->register($fname,$lname,$username,$email,$dob,$password,0);
    }
echo json_encode($register);
}else{
    $response=array();
    $response["error"]=1;
    $response["message"]="Enter a valid email";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

And Here is my c# code

```
void cameraCapture_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
        {
            //checking if everything went fine when capturing a photo
            if (e.TaskResult != TaskResult.OK)
                return;

            string userId = "10";
            string userHash = "40a6fe73f24b4c73f0d7943c8a41adcb";

            //preparing RestRequest by adding server url, parameteres and files...
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest("http://www.imanitv.com/shareyourtrip/addpost.php", Method.POST);
            request.AddParameter("fname", Fname);
            request.AddParameter("lname", Lname);
            request.AddParameter("username", Username);
            request.AddParameter("password", Password);
            request.AddParameter("dob", Dob);
            request.AddParameter("email", Email);
            //request.AddFile(ReadToEnd(e.ChosenPhoto));
            request.AddFile("photo", ReadToEnd(e.ChosenPhoto), "photo.jpg", "image/pjpeg");

            //calling server with restClient
            RestClient restClient = new RestClient();
            restClient.ExecuteAsync(request, (response) =>
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    //upload successfull
                    MessageBox.Show("Upload completed succesfully...\n" + response.Content);
                }
                else
                {
                    //error ocured during upload
                    MessageBox.Show(response.StatusCode + "\n" + response.StatusDescription);
                }
            });
        }

        //method for converting stream to byte[]
        public byte[] ReadToEnd(System.IO.Stream stream)
        {
            long originalPosition = stream.Position;
            stream.Position = 0;

            try
            {
                byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];

                int totalBytesRead = 0;
                int bytesRead;

                while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(readBuffer, totalBytesRead, readBuffer.Length - totalBytesRead)) > 0)
                {
                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

                    if (totalBytesRead == readBuffer.Length)
                    {
                        int nextByte = stream.ReadByte();
                        if (nextByte != -1)
                        {
                            byte[] temp = new byte[readBuffer.Length * 2];
                            Buffer.BlockCopy(readBuffer, 0, temp, 0, readBuffer.Length);
                            Buffer.SetByte(temp, totalBytesRead, (byte)nextByte);
                            readBuffer = temp;
                            totalBytesRead++;
                        }
                    }
                }

                byte[] buffer = readBuffer;
                if (readBuffer.Length != totalBytesRead)
                {
                    buffer = new byte[totalBytesRead];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(readBuffer, 0, buffer, 0, totalBytesRead);
                }
                return buffer;
            }
            finally
            {
                stream.Position = originalPosition;
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CameraCaptureTask cameraCapture = new CameraCaptureTask();
            cameraCapture.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(cameraCapture_Completed);
            cameraCapture.Show();
        }
```

And Here is the exception:

```
System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: uri
  Source=System
  ParamName=uri
  StackTrace:
       at System.UriBuilder..ctor(Uri uri)
       at RestSharp.RestClient.BuildUri(IRestRequest request)
       at RestSharp.RestClient.ConfigureHttp(IRestRequest request, IHttp http)
       at RestSharp.RestClient.ExecuteAsync(IRestRequest request, Action`2 callback, String httpMethod, Func`4 getWebRequest)
       at RestSharp.RestClient.ExecuteAsync(IRestRequest request, Action`2 callback)
       at RestSharp.RestClientExtensions.ExecuteAsync(IRestClient client, IRestRequest request, Action`1 callback)
       at RestSharpTrial.MainPage.cameraCapture_Completed(Object sender, PhotoResult e)
       at Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.ChooserBase`1.FireCompleted(Object sender, TTaskEventArgs e, Delegate fireThisHandlerOnly)
       at Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.CameraCaptureTask.OnInvokeReturned(Byte[] outputBuffer, Delegate fireThisHandlerOnly)
       at Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.GenericChooser.OnInvokeReturned(Byte[] outputBuffer, Delegate d)
       at Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.ChooserListener.OnChildTaskReturned(ChildTaskReturnedEventArgs args)
       at Microsoft.Phone.TaskModel.Interop.Task.FireOnChildTaskReturned(IntPtr returnDataPtr, UInt32 returnDataSize)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: It looks like you aren't handling a null argument - "ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code"

Comment: How do i work that out? How does one do that in this case.

Comment: You need to look into the docs, it looks like `RestClient` is expecting a uri

Answer (score 1):

RestSharp now requires you to set the BaseUrl of the RestClient as a Uri. Additionally it no longer allows the full url to be defined in the RestRequest. There was a bug reported about this that has been closed with comments indicating that it was intended for the base url to be set in the client then the requests would be relative to that client for reuse https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/606.

To fix your code change your request to a relative path

```
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("shareyourtrip/addpost.php", Method.POST);
```

then after creating your client, set the base url

```
RestClient restClient = new RestClient();
restClient.BaseUrl = new Uri("http://www.imanitv.com");
```